# Console gives me TypeError.. not a function message

Tags: javascript, appium, webdriver-io

I am trying to run tests using WebdriverIO/Appium. Here is how the code looks:

Page file :

```
const click_on_skip_button = () => {
    $("#com.ayoba.ayoba:id/onboard_skip").click();

    return;
}
const enter_name = () => { 
    const nameID =  driver.elementsByAccessibilityId("#com.ayoba.ayoba:id/name");
    nameID.keys("Dzanan");

    return; 
}

module.exports = {
    click_on_skip_button,
    enter_name
}
```

test file:

```
const { click_on_skip_button, enter_name}  = require("../pages/LandingPage") 

describe('Landing page tests', function(){
    it('Should verify all basic functionalities', () =>{
      // For demo purpose
      click_on_skip_button()
      enter_name();
    });
  });
```

error log:

```
0-0] 2019-10-04T12:15:42.350Z INFO webdriver: COMMAND findElement("css selector", "#com.ayoba.ayoba:id/onboard_skip")
[0-0] 2019-10-04T12:15:42.351Z INFO webdriver: [POST] http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub/session/199b590d-1fa2-4adb-8962-d5890c7bcd02/element
2019-10-04T12:15:42.351Z INFO webdriver: DATA { using: 'css selector',
  value: '#com.ayoba.ayoba:id/onboard_skip' }
[0-0] Error in "Landing page tests Should verify all basic functionalities"
TypeError: $(...).click is not a function
```

It would be awesome if someone could provide insight into whats wrong with my code. Thanks

Comment: `$(...)` looks a lot like jQuery or another library. Did you forget to include jQuery in your page?

Comment: Does the element `$("#com.ayoba.ayoba:id/onboard_skip")` exist?

Comment: @ConstantinGroß if the library was missing, then `$()` itself would have thrown an error before `.click(). It seems there is a *different* thing using `$`.